# The image set for button stays blank/white

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

What I want to do is change the image when I click on the button. This button works well but the image in my button stays blank. I have done some serious research before posting.

I looked at this first [Setting an image for a UIButton in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469474/setting-an-image-for-a-uibutton-in-code). While I wasn't sure if my image was nil or not I followed [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063581/displaying-image-in-uibutton) and this confirms me that my image isn't nil. I even [did this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640481/uibutton-custombutton-image-not-appearing) and I made sure again that the images where present in the Assets folder.

Here is what I get from my console:

> 2017-04-12 15:57:00.826779+0800  UIImage: 0x170284a10, {64, 64}
>
> 2017-04-12 15:57:00.976058+0800 UIImage: 0x1702808c0, {64, 64}
>
> 2017-04-12 15:57:01.110049+0800 UIImage: 0x170285140, {64, 64}
>
> 2017-04-12 15:57:01.275860+0800 UIImage: 0x170280910, {64, 64}

I have this:

In the .h file

```
- (IBAction)powerButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *powerButton;
```

In the .m file

```
- (IBAction)powerButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender {


   if (sender.selected) {
       UIImage *powerButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"power_off.png"];
       [powerButton setImage:powerButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.view addSubview:powerButton];
       NSLog(@"%@",powerButtonImage);
       [selectedDevice setPower:powerButton.selected];
       sender.selected = NO;
   } else {
       UIImage *powerButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"power_on.png"];
       [powerButton setImage:powerButtonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       [self.view addSubview:powerButton];
       NSLog(@"%@",powerButtonImage);
       [selectedDevice setPower:!powerButton.selected];
       sender.selected = YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909753/how-to-programmatically-set-my-uibutton-image-to-redraw

Comment: Are you insert image in asset or simple are adding in supporting file Please confirm

Comment: if it is in assest then use direct `power_on` in this place of `power_on.png`

Comment: I checked the link and made the changes, still have the same problem. And I add the images in the Assets.xcassets folder. I have other images in my app who works well.

Comment: Why don't you set image for power button for button state selected ? try to set image for selected state of button  with  [powerButton setImage:powerButtonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: in else part you are setting button state from normal to selected so you also need to provide image for selected state. please check it.

Comment: There is one more easy way is u can change image in story board for diffrent state like default and selected , so only u have to pass UIButton State.

Comment: Your Power Button having Outlet so why u are adding in subview?

Comment: @ravi.p I didn't know you could change image for different states. It is working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @F.Chen can i put an answer ? so u can accept ;)

Comment: @ravi.p Yes go on, helped me a lot! It has been days I am looking how to get it work!

Comment: @F.Chen answer Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using storyBoard

Easiest way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change only these lines

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
        UIImage *powerButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"power_off.png"];
        [powerButton setImage:powerButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *powerButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"power_on.png"];
         [powerButton setImage:powerButtonImage2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.view addSubview:powerButton];
    }

- (IBAction)powerButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender {


  sender.selected = !sender.selected;

}
```

Comment: It is what @Prince suggested and I made the changes but still, the images stays white/blanc. What I find strange it's, that my console shows me that the images are there. {64, 64} is the size of my images.

Comment: @F.Chen if my previous answer not working then try with my new answer once

Answer (score -1):

it think you should add frame

```
powerButton.frame =CGRectMake(x, y , width, height);
```